# How to add required in objects or array of objects in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to add a new field which it should be an object(array of objects). Like this

```
fieldname: {
            "lsjfld": String,
            "hgsfhsj": Number
           }
```

or like this

```
fieldname: [
            {"alfl": String},
            {"fjonf": Number}
           ]
```

And my requirement is, I want to add required for this "fieldname" field.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one add in a new line

```
required:[true, "this field cannot stay empty"]
```